# Кажется, у меня проблемы с логикой. Помогите

Tags: c

В общем, я изучаю Си уже 2-3 месяца. Сначала учил через ютуб, потом мне пришла книга по Си из валдберриса и я начал по нему обучаться.

Задания там такого типа: напишите программу, которая выводит таблицу умножения для этого числа; напишите программу, которая вычисляет факториал числа; напишите программу, которая переворачивает число; и.т.д.

Вроде задания лёгкие, НО В ПРОЦЕССЕ РЕАЛИЗАЦИИ СТАНОВИТСЯ ТРУДНО ДУМАТЬ КАК ЧТО СДЕЛАТЬ.

Я представляю, что будет вводить пользователь, какие условия будут, и.т.д. Но всё равно идёт как всегда через жо... Кхм

Не знаю, что делать. Что мне нужно развивать в себе, чтобы я смог с лёгкостью мог писать программы по заданиям (и не только из книги)?

Comment: Чтобы научиться что-то делать, нужно это делать. Чтобы научиться решать задачи - нужно решать задачи. Другого способа нет.

Comment: Вырабатывайте алгоритмическое мышление, решая задание на бумаге. Выписывайте, какие данные программа должна получить на вход, какой результат должен получиться на выходе. И путем каких преобразований из входных данных получатся выходные. А далее переносите все это в код.

Comment: Вопрос конечно мутный и не по теме, однако зря его так заминусовали. Тут же человек сам пытается что-то сделать, а не клянчит решение, как некоторые.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Гм, а с задачами по математике/геометрии в школе также было?
Просто похоже на эффект "неинтересно - не могу сосредоточиться"...

Может не тот формат задач/учебника?
Какая **цель**? Прежде всего *для чего* язык программирования и именно С? или С++?
По своему опыту знаю - чтобы начать программировать,надо погрузиться в это, чтобы код по ночам снился. Теория - хорошо, даже необходима. Но! **Кодить надо каждый день**, **1-2-3-8-25 часов** в сутки %) сколько получится выделить. Иногда мозги будут кипеть и будет хотеться выкинуть всё - учебник, компьютер и т.д. Но это учёба. Нет волшебной таблетки и методики - раз и начал понимать. Каждую мысль в учебнике - проверяй на практике. Пример - набирай и проверяй, смотри как работает, осваивай инструменты отладки, основы операционной системы (лучше линукс). Полезно в режиме командной строки поработать с компилятором, утилитой make и т.д. По самому языку - может зайдёт вот эта книга [Head First язык C](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/head-first-c/9781449335649/) - точно есть на торрентах, в онион сети и даркнете, старенькая но формат подачи материала интересный. Может имеет смысл поработать с условно-бесплатными курсами от яндекса или codecademy. (Тут гуглить надо).

В любом случае - успехов, веры в себя и ... терпения! Программирование - интересная сфера, но требует усилий и умения постоянно учиться новому, осваивать материал и справляться с рутиной.

Кстати, советую посмотреть бесплатные, но полезные ресурсы

[С++ от code-basics](https://code-basics.com/ru/languages/cpp)

[Здесь задачки разного уровня](https://codebattle.hexlet.io/)

[codewars - задачи разного уровня на разных языках](https://www.codewars.com/)

*update: Вспомнил ещё такой момент - иногда "заходит" такой метод - решаешь задачу по программированию на бумаге. Т.е. рисуешь алгоритм (не блок схему, а как сам представляешь), пишешь на русском языке как оно должно работать (по шагам), можешь напротив каждого шага написать переменные и что в них должно находиться (в IDE есть пошаговые отладчики тоже, но это потом). Потом пишешь на бумажке текст программы. Проверяешь на ПК. Двойной труд? Да, но иногда этот метод творит чудеса.

Answer (score 0):

Вот три сайта для решений задач.

Если что-то не понимаешь стоит смотреть разбор задач. Самое лучшее решение это прочитать, понять, закрыть, и попробовать решить не смотря каждые 5 секунд на разбор. Через месяц или два увидишь результат.

PS. Не долбись об задачи больше 3 часов

1. [ACMP](https://acmp.ru)
2. [LeetCode](https://leetcode.com)
3. [Codeforces](https://codeforces.com)

Comment: Похоже, здесь ссылки на задачи с подковыркой, а автору пока нужно с элементарными разобраться.

Comment: Есть еще [codewars](https://www.codewars.com/) Уровень задач от элементарных до головоломных

Comment: @MBo 1 ссылка хранит в себе элементарные задачки, просто надо отсортировать по сложности